# Why $Y=\{ f \in C^1([0,1]^n) : f(0)=0 \}$ is a closed subspace of codimension $1$

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose $C^1([0,1]^n)$ is the set of real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]^n$, whose derivative $\leq 1$ is continuous on $[0,1]^n$.

> Define $$Y=\{ f \in C^1([0,1]^n) : f(0)=0 \}$$ Why $Y$ is a closed subspace of codimension $1$?

The question is taken from the proof of [Lemma $15$](http://www.impan.pl/~pwojtas/Publikacje/freespaces.pdf).

Comment: For closed: Take a sequence in $Y$ which converges. Show that the limit has $f(0) = 0$ (which is actually obvious).

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ is the kernel of the surjective (and continuous) map

$$C^1([0,1]^n) \to \mathbb R, f \mapsto f(0).$$

In particular, $Y$ is closed (as a kernel) and of codimension $1$ (since $C^1([0,1]^n)/Y \cong \mathbb R$ is one-dimensional).

Comment: May I ask one more question? If $Y$ is a closed subspace of codimension $1$, why is it complemented?

Comment: Just take an algebraic complement (which exists for sure, this is simple linear algebra). Since it is finite-dimensional, it is automatically closed.